# How to avoid outer-scope values messing with using the MarkupBuilder?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I need an element named file in my xml, however the gradle project have a property named file which is called instead. What is the best way around this?

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

task test {
  def writer = new StringWriter()
  def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
  xml.elem1(test: 'fest') {
    elem2(a: 'b')
    file(c: 'd')
    elem4(e: 'f')
  }
  println(writer)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
xml.file( c: 'd' )
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I can't decide whether it is logical or not; maybe both. I guess this tells a little bit about the implementation. Somehow I thought it generated a tree of objects to invoke, but it seems like it's only the one and the state about current closure decides where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the 'delegate' variable, which is automatically made available within each XML element's code block.

For example:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

task test {
  def writer = new StringWriter()
  def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
  xml.elem1(test: 'fest') {
    elem2(a: 'b')
    delegate.file(c: 'd')
    elem4(e: 'f')
  }
  println(writer)
}
```

Comment: You already have the `delegate`, as it is the `MarkupBuilder` instance in the `xml` variable

Comment: I offer it as an alternative syntax which thoredge may or may not prefer.